# Change the color of text in a text area using <select> and Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text area within a simple website, where a user can type in what they like. I would like to add a selector(Dropdown box/Combobox) to change the color of all of the text within said text area.

full code

```js
function Text() {
        if(document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontWeight != 'bold')
            document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        else
            document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
    }
    function Text() {
        if(document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontStyle != 'italic')
            document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontStyle = 'italic';
        else
            document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontStyle = 'normal';
    }
    function Text() {
        if(document.getElementById("textarea").style.textDecoration != 'underline')
            document.getElementById("textarea").style.textDecoration = 'underline';
        else
            document.getElementById("textarea").style.textDecoration = 'none';
    }
     
     
    document.getElementById('colorChanger').addEventListener('change', changeColor);
     
    function changeColor() {
    var color = document.getElementById('colorChanger').value;
    var list = document.getElementById('textarea');
    list.style.color=color;
     
     
    }
```

```css
    body {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 10px;
        height: 7px;
        position: center;

    }
     
    h1 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 112px;
        color: #C0C0C0;
        text-align: center;
     
    }
     
    textarea {
        width: 90%;
        height: 450px;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid;
        background-color:;
        font-size: 16px;
        resize: none;
    }
     
    #Button {
        position: relative;
        top: 450px;
        left: 50px;
    }
     
    #Button {
        position: relative;
        top: 450px;
        left: 70px;
    }
     
    #Button {
        position: relative;
        top: 450px;
        left: 90px;
    }
    select {
        position: relative;
        top: -302px;
        left: 320px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    
    <html>
    <head>

     <title>Simple Word Processor</title>
     
     
    
  
    
    

    
    
    
    </head>
    
    
    
    <body>
    
        <button id="Button" type="button" onclick="boldText()">Bold</button>
        <button id="Button" type="button" onclick="italicText()">Italic</button>
        <button id="Button" type="button" onclick="underlineText()">Underline</button>
       


     
        <form id="form">
            <textarea id="textarea">Enter text here...</textarea>
        </form>
       
    
     
    <select id="colorChanger">
       <option value="#000">Black</option>
       <option value="#f00">Red</option>
       <option value="#00f">Blue</option>
       <option value="#0f0">Green</option>
    </select>
       
    
     
    </body>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    </html>
```

Comment: `id` in `document` should be unique. There should be at most one  `#textarea` element. If you are trying to select a single `textarea` element you can use `var list = document.querySelector("textarea")` and set `.color` at `list` element without `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById` will not return an array

```js
document.getElementById('colorChanger').addEventListener('change', changeColor);

function changeColor() {
var color = document.getElementById('colorChanger').value;
var list = document.getElementById('textarea1');
list.style.color=color;


}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1">Enter text here...</textarea>


<select id="colorChanger">
   <option value="#000">black</option>
   <option value="#f00">Red</option>
   <option value="#00f">Blue</option>
   <option value="#0f0">Green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, I have updated my post with further information if you are able to help me any more.

Comment: change the list[i] to list

Comment: i posted a new answer. Check it

Answer (score 2):

Just set `style.color` like below.

```
var list = document.getElementById('textarea');
list.style.color = color;
```

```js
document.getElementById('colorChanger').addEventListener('change', changeColor);

function changeColor() {
var color = document.getElementById('colorChanger').value;
var list = document.getElementById('textarea');
list.style.color = color;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">Enter text here...</textarea>


<select id="colorChanger">
   <option value="black">black</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, I have updated my post with further information if you are able to help me any more.

Comment: give a unique id to form textarea like `<textarea id="formtextarea">Enter text here...</textarea>` then try.then chage `var list = document.getElementById('formtextarea');` hope it woks.
`

Answer (score 1):

Created a fiidle for you [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Safoora/3vj0q40e/1/).

Using traditional javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc(val){
document.getElementById("textarea").style.color=val;
}
</script>

<textarea id="textarea">Enter text here...</textarea>


<select id="colorChanger"  onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="abc(this.value)">
   <option value="black">black</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

Updatee:

In yopu code add:

```
<script>
 function changeColor() {
    var color = document.getElementById('colorChanger').value;
   document.getElementById("textarea").style.color=color;
}</script>
```

in the header after style tag.

also you not calling function onchange of select tag. add this in select tag.

```
<select id="colorChanger" onchange="changeColor()">
```

Comment: thankyou, any possibility you could do it in plain old javascript opposed to jquery?

Comment: no luck unfortunately, I'm starting to think there is something wrong with my whole code

Comment: updated answer.  also refer: https://fiddle.jshell.net/Safoora/503n2hL5/7/

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @6A-6F-45 why did you suggest deleting my answer?

Comment: Thanks @g00glen00b

Comment: @techhunter no problem. To answer your question why the OP suggested to delete your answer, most likely he wishes to remove this question all together, but he can't since there are upvotes on certain answers. So that's why he edited both your post and his own question to "need to delete". He is even banned right now (I guess for the same reason). You don't have to approve that though.

Answer (score 0):

You combined my previous code with a comment in your question you changed my `getElementById` to `getElementByTagName` and it should be `getElementsByTagName` you missed the `s` and it will return an array whereas `getElementById` will return an object

```js
 
function boldText() {
    if(document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontWeight != 'bold')
        document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    else
        document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
}
function italicText() {
    if(document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontStyle != 'italic')
        document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontStyle = 'italic';
    else
        document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontStyle = 'normal';
}
function underlineText() {
    if(document.getElementById("textarea").style.textDecoration != 'underline')
        document.getElementById("textarea").style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    else
        document.getElementById("textarea").style.textDecoration = 'none';
}
 
 
document.getElementById('colorChanger').addEventListener('change', changeColor);
 
function changeColor() {
var color = document.getElementById('colorChanger').value;
var list = document.getElementById('textarea');
list.style.color=color;
 
 
}
```

```css
 
body {
    border: 3px solid #C0C0C0 ;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 700px;
    position: center;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #f8f8f8;
    outline-width: 10000px;
}
 
h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 112px;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    position: relative;
    top: -220px;
    text-align: center;
 
}
 
textarea {
    width: 90%;
    height: 450px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 16px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -305px;
    left: 50px;
}
 
#boldButton {
    position: relative;
    top: 450px;
    left: 50px;
}
 
#italicButton {
    position: relative;
    top: 450px;
    left: 70px;
}
 
#underlineButton {
    position: relative;
    top: 450px;
    left: 90px;
}
select {
    position: relative;
    top: -302px;
    left: 320px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Word Processor</title>
</head>
<body>
 
    <button id="boldButton" type="button" onclick="boldText()">Bold</button>
    <button id="italicButton" type="button" onclick="italicText()">Italic</button>
    <button id="underlineButton" type="button" onclick="underlineText()">Underline</button>
   
    <canvas></canvas>
 
    <h1> Word Processor </h1>
 
    <form id="form">
        <textarea id="textarea">Enter text here...</textarea>
    </form>
   
 
 
 
 
 
<select id="colorChanger">
   <option value="#000">Black</option>
   <option value="#f00">Red</option>
   <option value="#00f">Blue</option>
   <option value="#0f0">Green</option>
</select>
   
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Still no luck, is there something seriously wrong with my code?

Comment: did you run it here?

Comment: click on the Run Code Snippet` button

Comment: I have changed my question code to what I have currently, the same as the working version you have created here, but it does not work for me?

Comment: i just added your question to snippet. Whether the snippet is working for you? are you on computer or mobile?

Comment: Hi, it is working for me now, just an error on my part. Thanks for all of your help!